# *nix - can readdir64 be used on a 32-bit system?

Tags: c, linux, unix, dirent.h

I am currently writing a filesystem library and have come across `readdir64()` while coding the *nix side of the lib. The documentation for this function says that it takes a `dirent64*` and adds support for large file systems; does that mean it only works on x86-64 systems?

Comment: Avoid it...treat it like the plague it is.  Implement `readdir()` and make it correct.  Don't quote me on it, but I think `readdir64()` is for use on 32-bit systems that need to work with large files and therefore need bigger sizes than 32-bit integers.  If that's correct, there's no need for `readdir64()` on 64-bit systems.

Comment: But in `dirent.h` for systems with `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64` defined (64-bit systems) `readdir()` is defined like this `#define readdir readdir64`.

So it is the default on 64-bit systems.

Comment: OK; like I said, don't quote me on it.  It depends on different systems rules for backwards compatibility, etc.  It is weird stuff.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode AFAIR `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64` is supposed to be set by the programmer if they need "huge files support". The best practice seems to be to always use `readdir()` and to define the right symbols for doing what is needed.

Comment: sorry, the brackets were meant to read "(and 64-bit systems)" because in the header file there is a

`#ifdef "32 bit define"`
`#elif __USE_FILE_OFFSET64`
`#else`

With readdir defined as readdir64 for all but the 32-bit variant

Comment: The usual way is to #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 , which forces all file access to use the 64 bit variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to old linux discussions from the time of 32bit PCs (http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-glibc/2001-03/msg00047.html), readdir64 CAN be used on 32-bit systems.

Ulrich Drepper's (glibc lead contributor and maintainer) reply also says you SHOULD use readdir64. Post is from way back in 2001: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-glibc/2001-03/msg00048.html